# How do I get my laptop not to lock up every time I close the lid in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: laptop, power-management

Every time I close my laptop lid, Ubuntu 13.04 will lock up.  I have it set in the Power settings to do nothing for when I close the lid on both battery power and when plugged in, yet when I do close the lid, the system seems to lock up.  Note, the mouse will move as normal, and it looks like nothing is wrong.  But when I try to click or press any buttons, the system is unresponsive.  I have to power cycle the laptop and re-boot in order to continue using it.  Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,

John

Answer (score 1):

Under settings go into the Power section and change "When lid is closed" to "Do nothing"

Answer (score 0):

that's because the settings that you are looking for are not in the power management section, go in **Brightness & Lock**

Edit: it could also be some kind of issue, see if you solve with this new settings.

Comment: I have lock disabled, the only option I have enabled is the dimming of the screen when inactive for 10 minutes.